# Subscribe synchronization in ionic

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, observable, subscribe

I have a problem with synchronization.
Exemple, I hava two methods:

```
methodOne.subscribe((resp){
    return resp;
});

methodoTwo(resp).subscribe((resp2){     
    return resp2; 
});
```

Method Two is running before method one returns. Is there any solution to solve this synchronization problem without putting method two inside one?
I use ionic 3.

Comment: is methodTwo call dependant on methodOne response?

Comment: Exact, the methodTwo is dependant of methodOne.

Comment: Since `Promise` and `Observable` are asynchronous, this is hard. Check out `await` although you need a `Promise` and not sure if it works well with ionic. Else your answer is basically 'no', or just provide a workaround so the code looks neat but the subscribtions are still nested

Answer (score 1):

if methodOne and methodTwo() is observable then you do

```
methodOne.swichMap((resp)=>methodoTwo(resp)).subscribe()
```

Comment: Maybe it would work in the example I gave above, but it was just an example to try to illustrate the situation.
In the project there are other functions and calls between subscribes and I'm having problems with synchronization.
I do not know if it exists in Ionic, but I thought of trying something like semaphores used in C ++ to work with thread synchronization, but I do not know if it is the best solution either.

Comment: If u can illustrate the async flow I can try to help. There are a lot of operators u can us in rxjs for different use case.